# Retrieve line from eval string that caused an error

Tags: ruby, eval, rescue

To start- I know the risks and have taken precautions for using `eval`- not the question I'm asking here.

I'd like to retrieve a stack trace/proper error line from using `eval`, potentially using a multi-line code string that's entered in, and I'd like to grab the line from the eval string that failed.

```
eval_str = <<EOF
def illegal_stuff
  5 / 0 # This will cause a crash
end

5 + 2
illegal_stuff
42
EOF

begin
  eval(eval_str)
rescue => ex
  ex.backtrace # ???
end
```

Somehow, I'd like to retrieve the string `"5 / 0 # This will cause a crash"` 
The backtrace doesn't seem to have a line number, character count, or anything like that.

I've tried adding `eval(eval_str, binding, "__FILE__", "__LINE__")` - but not noticing a difference.

Is there any way to retrieve a line number/position/anything that can help me to retrieve the line of code that cause the problem?

Comment: Why are you sending `__FILE__` in as a string? That sort of defeats the point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of pushing the error closer to the origin:

```
def yolo(code)
  from = caller_locations.first

  eval(code, binding, from.path, from.lineno)
end

yolo <<END
1/0
END
```

Where you get errors like:

```
yolo.rb:7:in `/': divided by 0 (ZeroDivisionError)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The backtrace doesn't seem to have a line number, character count, or anything like that.

Doesn't it? This works on my Ruby:

```
begin
  eval(eval_str)
rescue => ex
  eval_str.lines[ex.backtrace.first[/^\(eval\):(\d+):/, 1].to_i - 1]
end
```